# How to clear user cookies after pressing the SharePoint 2013 out-of-the-box signout button

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, forms-authentication, cookie, internal-server-error

I have implemented a custom form based authentication solution. However when user click the OOTB signout button, a http 500 internal server error is thrown.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/d9d682d8-b05c-4188-9750-418e1c862fc6/sign-out-error-forms-based-authentication

http://blog.lekman.com/2012/07/resolved-sign-out-from-forms.html

i know that the issue lies with the user cookies. however im not sure where/how can i clear the user cookies programmatically, is there a way to add in code to the signout.aspx?

Answer (score 1):

```
private void ExpireAllCookies()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
    {
        int cookieCount = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Count;
        for (var i = 0; i < cookieCount; i++)
        {
            var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[i];
            if (cookie != null)
            {
                var cookieName = cookie.Name;
                var expiredCookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName) {Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)};
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(expiredCookie); // overwrite it
            }
        }

        // clear cookies server side
        HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: hi Michal, i tried adding your code to the signout.aspx by adding 
<script runat=server>
[your code]
</script>
but it still didn't solve my issue

Comment: @user1166085 FYI, this is Server-Side not Client-side code

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + F5 response for reload all scripts in your browser Ctrl + Shift + Delete open properites where you can delete all cookies from browser cache

Comment: i wish to do this programmatically, is there a way to add in code to the signout.aspx?

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
private void RemoveCookiesAndSignOut()
{
    // Clear session state. 
    if (Context.Session != null)
    {
        Context.Session.Clear();
    }

    string cookieValue = string.Empty;
    if (Context.Request.Browser["supportsEmptyStringInCookieValue"] == "false")
        cookieValue = "NoCookie";

    // Clear my own cookie.
    HttpCookie cookieWinSignIn = Context.Request.Cookies["Morpheus_WindowsSignedIn"];
    if (cookieWinSignIn != null)
    {
        cookieWinSignIn.Value = cookieValue;
        Context.Response.Cookies.Remove("Morpheus_WindowsSignedIn");
        Context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookieWinSignIn);
    }

    // Remove cookies for authentication. 
    HttpCookie cookieSession = Context.Request.Cookies["WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated"];
    if (cookieSession != null)
    {
        cookieSession.Value = cookieValue;
        Context.Response.Cookies.Remove("WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated");
        Context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookieSession);
    }

    HttpCookie cookiePersist = Context.Request.Cookies["MSOWebPartPage_AnonymousAccessCookie"];
    if (cookiePersist != null)
    {
        cookiePersist.Value = cookieValue;
        cookiePersist.Expires = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        Context.Response.Cookies.Remove("MSOWebPartPage_AnonymousAccessCookie");
        Context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookiePersist);
    }

    // Sign out.
    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut();
}
```

Or

```
jQuery(function ($) {
var removedLinks = 'removedLinks'
,Options = {
expires: 7,
path: '/news'
},
c=$.cookie(removedLinks)||'#DebuggingCode'
$(c).remove();
$(".NewsHider a").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var LinkClass = '.'+ $(this).attr('id'),
removeLinksClasses=c.split(',')
$(LinkClass).remove()
removeLinksClasses.push(LinkClass)
c=removeLinksClasses.join(',') 
$.cookie(removedLinks, c, Options)
});
$('#NewsResetCookie').click(function(){
$.cookie(removedLinks,'',{expires:-1,path:'/news'})
})
});
```

to do this, edit the file at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\signout.aspx
Modify function _spBodyOnLoad()
Add code to clear cookie before window.close().